# Gulp not reacting to changes in theme file with understrap

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm creating a Wordpress theme from scratch using a full course tutorial on how to make one.
I'm just following the steps but it goes wrong where I want to set up gulp so it can preview the changes in the sass file.

After a day of debugging errors, I finally got it working as it says "Gulp watching", which means it's waiting for changes in the sass file.

But for some reason, it's just not doing anything.I tried editing some css but it won't do anything.. Is there anyone who had this issue and got it working?

Comment: Which version of `understrap` are you using? [`Gulp.js` was removed after `Understrap 1.0`](https://understrap.com/blog/understrap-1-0-is-here/)

`Instead of commands like “gulp watch”, you would just use “npm run watch”.`

Comment: You can also refer to `NPM and the Build Process / Running` [in the official documentation](https://docs.understrap.com/#/understrap-child/npm?id=running)